# how can I pass a number larger than 9 to a psycopg2 select statement

Tags: python, python-requests, psycopg2

I have a simple Flask app. The app connects with a database of movie reviews. I built a function to retrieve data which takes a max_count argument. but for some reason, I can only pass a number smaller than 10.  The app works fine if I pass 3 or 9. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import json
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello!"

@app.route('/get_total_data_count/<label>', methods=['GET'])
def get_total_data_count(label):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="barmej", password="password", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", database="labeling")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        if label == 'positive':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data_labeling WHERE label_number = 0 limit 100;")
        elif label == 'negative':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data_labeling WHERE label_number = 1 limit 100;")
        elif label == 'all':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data_labeling;")
        return "The count is " + str(cursor.rowcount)
    except:
        return "Error! type: positive, negative or all"
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data_test():
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="barmej", password="password", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", database="labeling")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        max_count = request.args.get('max_count')
        sort_order = request.args.get('sort_order')
        if sort_order == 'ASC':
            insert = "SELECT text FROM data_input ORDER BY ASC limit %s"
            parameters = max_count
            cursor.execute(insert, parameters)
            result = cursor.fetchall()

        elif sort_order == 'DESC':
            insert = "SELECT text FROM data_input ORDER BY DESC limit %s "
            parameters = max_count
            cursor.execute(insert, (parameters))
            result = cursor.fetchall()

        dic = {}
        dic['text'] = result
        return dic
    except:
        return "Error!, make sure url include: a max count and either 'ASC' or 'DESC' Argument"
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

The call is done in python shell from the server:

```
>>> import requests
>>> param = {'max_count': 12, 'sort_order': 'ASC'}
>>> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/get_data', params=param)
>>> r.text
```

I tried the code without the exception and the error is:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%"\nLINE 1: SELECT text FROM data_input limit %s
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you're passing the parameter to `.execute()`

You need to pass a tuple like this:

```
cursor.execute(insert, (parameters,)) # a comma is necessary to make a tuple
```

Currently when there is multiple digits it thinks those are separate parameters.